# Mostrar datos especificos de un array asociativo PHP

Tags: php

Necesito extraer de un array asociativo unos datos específicos y mostrarlos , en este ejemplo los elementos son solo 2 entonces lo hice sin iterar pero necesito saber si hay una manera mas óptima de obtener y mostrar los datos ya que en el caso de tener 50 pares clave-valor no sabré tan fácil el índice de la clave.

```
  $arrayNotas= array("Laura" => 9,"Xavier"=>4);
        
        $notaLaura=  $arrayNotas["Laura"];   //obtengo valores
        $notaXavier=$arrayNotas["Xavier"];
        $claves= array_keys($arrayNotas);   //array de claves, solo son 2...
        $media = $notaLaura+$notaXavier/2;

        echo "La nota mas alta es la de " .$claves[0]."  con un ".$notaLaura."<br>"; //si hay mas valores como podría hacer?
        echo "La nota mas baja es la de " .$claves[1]."  con un ".$notaXavier."<br>";
        echo "La nota media de clase es ". $media;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hallar la nota mínima de una forma relativamente sencilla con [`min()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-min-function/#:%7E:text=The%20min()%20function%20of,value%20among%20the%20passed%20parameters.)

```
$minNota = min($arrayNotas);
```

Tenemos el valor, pero no el elemento, entonces usamos [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php)

```
$minNota = min($arrayNotas);
$notaMinNombre = array_search($minNota, $arrayNotas);
```

Y para la nota más alta [`max()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.max.php)

```
$maxNota = max($arrayNotas);
$notaMaxNombre = array_search($maxNota, $arrayNotas);
```

Y la media con un [`array_sum()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sum.asp)

```
$media = array_sum($arrayNotas) / count($arrayNotas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso del bucle [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php). Su implementación para tu caso sería así:

```
foreach ($arraynotas as $clave => $valor)
{
    echo "La nota de $clave es: $valor";
}
```

Comment: No me sirve ya que a la salida hay que concatenarle  "La nota mas alta es la de " y el bucle devuelve todos los elementos

Comment: Cierto, no había leído correctamente la pregunta. También se podría resolver de esta forma sumando cada valor en una variable pero la otra respuesta es más correcta y más sencilla que la mía.